# What is JAXB generated package-info.java

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to find some information on what the `package-info.java` file generated by the JAXB **xjc** commandline app actually does. All that is in the file is

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.com", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package the.generated.package.path;
```

What is this `package-info.java` file used for?

Comment: That search actually isn't very helpful. Isn't it better to link directly to questions that you think provide useful information, rather than a search page which can change over time?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

package-info.java is a way to apply java annotations at the package level. In this case Jaxb is using package-level annotations to indicate the namespace, and to specify namespace qualification for attributes [(source)](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/jaxb20-fcs/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html).

Answer (score 7):

This is also useful when you generate javadoc

> package-info.java - Can contain a package declaration, package
>   annotations, package comments and Javadoc tags. This file is new in
>   JDK 5.0, and is preferred over package.html.

source : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#sourcefiles

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define default namespace for elements in your java model, you can define it in package-info.java