# How do I specifiy the same namespace for all java classes when I want to generate a xsd-file with jaxb2?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have an XML file to configure a program. The XML configuration is un-marshalled with jaxb. I figured it would be a useful thing to generate an XSD file from these classes to make it easier for other developers to change the settings and to avoid errors.

One can use a XSD file without a namespace but than the jaxb2 post-processing tools won't work (I am stuck with the name "schema1.xsd" without having the possibility to change that on creation).

Below you can see how to "import" a XSD file into your XML file without namespace:

```xml
<rootTag
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/path/to/the/file/schema1.xsd">
<subTags>
</subTags>
</rootTag>
```

I found some blogs stating that one should add a namespace to the `@XmlRootElement` like `@XmlRootElement(namespace = "myNameSpace") but what shall I do when I have classes using instances of other classes?

Below you can see a simplification of my classes:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "library")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Library {
    // creates a wrapper around a List
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "books")
    // lists this tag
    @XmlElement(name = "book")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    private Address address;

    private String nameOfLibrary;
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String town;
}
```

When I add the namespace only to my first class (Library) than jaxb generates a schema1.xsd file only for Library.java with the namespace which imports a second XSD file schema2.xsd whit all the other objects.

When I add the namespcae to every XmlRootElement and XmlElement, there is still a seperation between schema2.xsd and schema1.xsd

Below you can see the plugin settings:

```xml
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>schemagen</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>schemagen</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sources>
            <source>src/main/java/de/soptim/za/tools/backup/checking/config</source>
        </sources>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/schema</outputDirectory>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

```xml
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Maybe I am also misunderstanding the namespace concept, I am rather confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your JAXB-annotated classes (`Library`, `Address`, `Book`) are all in
a common package, which seems to be `de.soptim.za.tools.backup.checking.config`.
Then you can put a `package-info.java` file into this package,
annotate the package with `@XmlSchema` and specify a namespace there.

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://mynamespace.com",
           elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
           attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNSET)
package de.soptim.za.tools.backup.checking.config;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

See also the [API doc of `@XmlSchema`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) and this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501494/what-is-jaxb-generated-package-info-java).

For marshalling/unmarshalling this namespace will apply to all
your JAXB classes of that package
(except of course where you explicitly set another namespace in
any individual `@XmlElement`, `@XmlElementWrapper`, `@XmlAttribute` or `@XmlRootElement`
annotation within your classes).

And when generating schemas from the classes of this package
you should only get one XSD file generated,
because your classes use only one namespace.